# Access specific children on anytree

Tags: python, tree, anytree

I have started using `anytree` but currently facing some challenge iterating on my tree.

Test tree:

```
top = Node("top", keywords="topleveltree")
hello = Node("hello", keywords="hello", parent=top)
hello1 = Node("hello X", keywords="hello X", answer="Say hello to X", parent=hello)
hello2 = Node("hello Y", keywords="hello Y", answer="Say hello to Y", parent=hello)
goodbye = Node("goodbye", keywords="goodbye", parent=top)
goodbye1 = Node("goodbye X", keywords="goodbye X", answer="Say goodbye to X", parent=goodbye)
```

RenderTree:

`Node('/top', keywords='topleveltree')
├── Node('/top/hello', keywords='hello')
│   ├── Node('/top/hello/hello X', answer='Say hello to X', keywords='hello X')
│   └── Node('/top/hello/hello Y', answer='Say hello to Y', keywords='hello Y')
└── Node('/top/goodbye', keywords='goodbye')
    └── Node('/top/goodbye/goodbye X', answer='Say goodbye to X', keywords='goodbye X')`

My script retrieve the first level of my tree (/top/hello and /top/goodbye) and now I'm basically trying to get whatever is below them (especially keywords and answer).

I have been able to achieve this using multiple ways such as `hello.descendants` or just using `LevelOrderIter(hello)`, however I'm trying now to do the same using some kind of python logic (where the variable is now a string).

I tried to run Node(hello).descendants but it returns an empty array. However if I run `type(hello)` and `type(Node('hello'))` both returns `<class 'anytree.node.node.Node'>`

ex:

```
categories = ['hello','goodbye']
for category in categories:
    print category # string
    print Node(category) # Node('/hello')
    print hello # Node('/top/hello', keywords='hello')
    hello.descendants # ok
    Node(category).descendants # ()

[node.name for node in PreOrderIter(hello, maxlevel=3)] # ok
[node.name for node in PreOrderIter(Node('hello'), maxlevel=3)] # return empty
```

I have very little experience with tree, so I guess I'm missing something basic, but can't find what.

Answer (score 0):

To access the tree childer we can use the index. Like parent.children[1].name this give me the the data of child 1 in the tree. see the code below

by this Code I am just creating children:

```
Start_point={
            "man":False,
           "goat":False,
           "lion":False,
           "grass":False,
            "state":True
          }
udo = Node(Start_point)


# East conditions
temp=dict(udo.name)
for i in temp:
    if(temp["state"]==True):
        temp=dict(udo.name)
        if (i=="man" and temp["man"]==False):
            left=dict(temp)
            left["man"]=True
            Node(left,parent=udo)

        if (temp["man"]==False):
            temp["man"]=True
            if (i=="goat" and temp["goat"]==False):
                mid1=dict(temp)
                mid1["goat"]=True
                Node(mid1,parent=udo)
            elif (i=="lion" and temp["lion"]==False):
                mid2=dict(temp)
                mid2["lion"]=True
                Node(mid2,parent=udo)
            elif (i=="grass" and temp["grass"]==False):
                right=dict(temp)
                right["grass"]=True
                Node(right,parent=udo)


for pre, fill, node in RenderTree(udo):
       print("%s%s" % (pre, node.name))
```

result of this:

```
{'man': False, 'goat': False, 'lion': False, 'grass': False, 'state': True}
├── {'man': True, 'goat': False, 'lion': False, 'grass': False, 'state': True}
├── {'man': True, 'goat': True, 'lion': False, 'grass': False, 'state': True}
├── {'man': True, 'goat': False, 'lion': True, 'grass': False, 'state': True}
└── {'man': True, 'goat': False, 'lion': False, 'grass': True, 'state': True}
```

Main code to access child:

```
udo.children[1].name
```

Result:

```
{'man': True, 'goat': True, 'lion': False, 'grass': False, 'state': True}
```

by this I got the data of `child[1]`

and by changing index I am able to get the specific child.

Comment: Your code is little bit difficult to understand this concept so I make my code. To let you understand of this problem.